# R - How to remove 'seperation' line and backround borcers in single plot / multi-plot grids

Tags: r, cowplot

This is driving me nuts. Have two `ggplot` objects `p` and `q` and use the elegant `cowplot::plot_grid` function to combine both plots in said grid. However I do get a kind of separation line between the two arranged plots. I use the code below.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)
comb <- plot_grid(p, q, labels = c('A', 'B'), 
              nrow = 2, ncol = 1, 
              align = "h", 
              label_fontfamily = "serif",
              greedy = TRUE,
              label_size = 12)
    
comb <- comb + panel_border(remove = TRUE)
save_plot("plot_combined.pdf", comb)
```

My questions are the following:

1. How can I **remove the separation line**?
2. How can I **increase the 'spacing' between the two plots** to avoid having the *label interfere with the y axis title*?

[image: Grid-arranged plot]

Comment: 1. please provide code to create p & q - to make the question reproducible. 2. I doubt the line comes from plot_grid - most likely it is from the individual plots. 3. to increase spacing, change the margins in the individual plots themselves

Comment: You were completely right. I looked into the right arguments to adjust and now everything works as supposed. Not adjusting the ```plot.background``` was the culprit, while I was looking only for arguments with ```xyz.border```. Thanks for nudging me into the right direction dww!

Comment: Glad that fixed it. voting to close as a typo, as the issue was unrelated to the plot_grid function

Comment: Edited the title of my question to better reflect that. Provided 'my answer' but can only close/accept it in 2 days. If you know how, you can also close this question right now.

Thanks again for your assisistance. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick was to adjust my theme as following:

```
p + theme(plot.background = element_blank()) # This did the trick for me!
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You might look at the ggarrange function in the "ggpubr" package.  I find it more user friendly than cowplot.

```
library(ggpubr)
ggarrange(p, q, ncol = 1, nrow = 2, labels = "AUTO")
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but the gray lines exist here also, and there is no mentioning in https://rpkgs.datanovia.com/ggpubr/reference/ggarrange.html how to get rid of them.